Can Cox or Fine-Gray model include exposure that occurs during observation?
I'm making a Fine-Gray model about pregnancy, but I notice that some pregnancy complications may occur during the observation instead of at the beginning of it because those complications are often found by examine during the observation, and it's hard to find the exact time of occurrence, besides, before reaching the diagnosis criteria, they often already have some potential impact. I've done the ph test, none-of them had significance, can I just think that although these complications may occur during the observation, they have "pre-diagnosis impact" and ph test shows their effects do not change over time, so it can be handled as exposures that occur at the beginning of the observation and be included in the Fine-Gray model?

what is the ph test?
